# Replace (ss) with something else

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem in PHP with replacing (ss) in a string.

```
$string = 'I want a new (ss) now!';
$newString = preg_replace('\(ss\)', 'car', $string);
```

I am expecting $newString to become:

> I want a new car now!

What am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `str_replace`

```
$string = 'I want a new (ss) now!';
$newString = str_replace('(ss)', 'car', $string);
```

example http://codepad.org/2wcYtL8E

**Output**

> I want a new car now!

## EDIT

Example with `preg_replace`

http://codepad.org/CFmSDTjR

```
$string = 'I want a new (ss) now!';
$newString = preg_replace('$\(ss\)$', 'car', $string);
```

**Output**

> I want a new car now!

Comment: Thanks! I am new to regex, and thought it would be nice to use it hehe

Comment: @mnstrflkrn You shouldn't use things because you think they are *nice*. You should use them if they're the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is your regex doesn't have [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

However, seeing as you're not using any regex features, you'd be better off using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$newString = str_replace("ss", "car", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

use str_replace()

```
$newString = str_replace("(ss)", "car", $string);
```